# Add a button to insert form input field dynamically using jscript or jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, jscript

First of all, this is NOT a duplicate question!

I want to use a button that when user clicks it, another field will be added to the form dynamically and then the button will be removed.

I read previous question about this issue ,but I want it to use a function to do this.

The codes are:

```
function add_field(day,id){
   var i = id;
   $(this).remove();
   i++;
   $('#'+day+'_exercise').append('<div class=\"form_row\"><day>Exercise'+i+':</day><input type=\"text\" name=\"'+day+'_exercise[]\" value=\"\" class=\"text_input fieldex\" onkeypress=\"return tabE(this,event)\" id=\"'+day+'_exercise\" /><cal>Set: </cal><input type=\"text\" name=\"'+day+'_exercise_set[]\" value=\"\" class=\"text_input fieldcal\" onkeypress=\"return tabE(this,event)\" id=\"'+day+'_exercise_set[]\" /><cal>Repeat: </cal><input type=\"text\" name=\"'+day+'_exercise_repeat[]\" value=\"\" class=\"text_input fieldcal\" onkeypress=\"return tabE(this,event)\" id=\"'+day+'_exercise_repeat[]\" /></div>');  
};
```

and

```
<button type="button" id="add_{$v1[1]}" onclick="add_field({$v1[1]},{$b_id})">+</button>
```

The code does not work at all! Where's the problem?

Comment: Could you give fiddle link

Comment: The onclick handler in your HTML is not very helpful as the parameters passed are not understandable.

However, I have hardcoded those values and created a pen for your reference. You need to pass in the element that you want to remove as 'this' to the handler. Here's the pen https://codepen.io/faisalrashid/pen/RwboOxL